# Finding closest time before/after another time

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I have a database of time's that are not necessarily exact to the specified time. For example, if I want to pick 12:00 PM and my columns have times in column A: 
[9:00 AM, 11:55 AM, 2:00 PM, 6:00 PM],
The closest before would be 11:55 AM, and closest after would be 2:00 PM. My attempt at the code:

```
=MAXIF(A:A, A:A, 12:00)
=MINIF(A:A, A:A, 12:00)
```

But to no avail, anythoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the max where the time is less than or equal to the criteria and the Min for the time greater than or equal to the criteria:

```
=MAXIFS(A:A, A:A,"<=12:00")
=MINIFS(A:A, A:A,">=12:00")
```

[image]

Comment: So the specific code I have for this context is:
    =MINIFS(A3:A535,A3:A535,>=T3)

Where T3 might be 12:00, or another time. However, I'm getting a "formula parse error"? Also, this is in Google Spreadsheets if that helps

Comment: 1. If this is google sheets why tag it `Excel`.  2. you need to put the `>=` in quotes `">=" & T3`

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll be more cognizant next time.
I keep getting answer "0", which i know is false because the expected answer would be 2:00, which is definitely in the list I"m referring to

Comment: Then maybe there is a problem with your data. like it maybe text and not true times.